# Switch VueJS Devtools back on in development

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, webpack

I tried running `npm run production` in my homestead development environment to see if the vuejs devtools will disappear and basically to make sure nothing broke also. Safe to say everything worked and the vuejs devtools went away. Now I'm having trouble bringing it back...

I ran `npm run dev` in hopes it'll restore it back to development mode but unfortunately it did not :(

Right now after running `npm run dev` the devtools is still unavailable and vuejs is still in production. I would like to go back to having the devtools and switching vuejs back to development in my homestead.

Comment: I had the same situation – try to close & open devtools / restart browser. Generally `npm run dev` should bring the vue tab back

Answer (score 0):

If `npm run dev` actually runs the default scripts it should do what you want. You probably see the cached files in your browser. Maybe have a look at [cache busting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting)